# How to create a URL from an iView, where i-URL is not present in an SAP Portal?

Tags: url, sap-enterprise-portal

How to create a URL from an iView, where the URL is not present in an SAP Portal?

I want to create a direct link from a iView (content administration-> portal content->iview) but that particular iView has no URL (Web Dynpro). Is there any way, to create a direct link?

Comment: A direct link to the iView or to the content in the iView? Java WebDynpro or ABAP WebDynpro?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have an URL to access directly a portal iview, where the iview is not associated with a given url (ie. not a webdynpro or equivalent).

I think that you can set the alias in the iview properties, and then access the iview using the url with the alias :

```
http(s)://portal:port/irj/alias
```

However, you have to check the autorisations of the iview.
Warning : I only used this on a page, on portal 7.01 and the user had to have a correct role (ie one giving access to that page).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to directly access your iView from another resource. You can do this in a several ways:

1. Navigate to Content Administrator -> your iView -> right click it and select Preview. This will give you working but not beautiful link, which would be randomly generated.
2. Navigate to System Administration -> System Configuration -> Runtime Settings -> Short URLs. There you will find short URLs for every page of portal. As well as long ones.  
   The only thing you should do is to add this url to your portal adress.

Long URL template:

```
http://[myServer]:[port_no]/irj/portal?NavigationTarget=ROLES://portal_content/every_user/[path_to_your_application]
```

Short URL template:

```
http://[myServer]:[port_no]/irj/portal?NavigationTarget=navurl://b3d6d9ebac16a46574d62757803b05d4
```

However, it should be noted that in both ways iView should be a part of a Role. For further help refer to [SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/b3/7b8163404448e7aad7899c0b30313e/content.htm).